# How do I use Command line to open and print or just print multiple pdf files?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a folder with quite a few pdf reports in it that I would like to setup to print automatically using the Task Scheduler in Windows and command lines to open adobe, the specific files, and then print them all. The problem I keep running into is that when I just print it gives useless sheets of paper with garbage on them. If I open adobe, as stated above, then open the files and then print them, it will only open the first in the list when I use the `*.pdf` to indicate all pdf files. Even after closing that first one it won't open the subsequent ones. Any idea as to how to get it to open and print all of them?

Here is the current command line that I am attempting to use:

```
start acrord32.exe /n /t "H:\My Analyzer\PDF - Excel\Physician Monthly Reports\*.pdf"
```

Comment: `​lp -- *.pdf​`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can print one using the command line parameters, then to print them all you create a batch file like

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) Do start acrord32.exe /n /t %%f
```

See [here for more info on for](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

This question over at Stack Overflow may help:

[Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/619158/94928)

Looks like for starters you need to pass the driver and portname to the `/t` switch.